# Primesense driver for Labview

Tags: driver, labview, primesense

I am trying to initialize the Primesense Carmine 1.09 using Labview. So far when trying to use OpenNi drivers but they appear to be broken...(I think the problem is with the openni.net.dll). Does anyone know if there is a driver that fits Labview? Or any other solution?

The error I get: "You have connected a refnum of one type to a refnum of another type and both types are members of some class hierarchy, but there is neither a simple up cast nor type cast between the two classes."

Comment: Could you provide links to the DLL, drivers and the specific refnum that fail?

Comment: I think I know what the source of the problem. I cannot find the OpenNIModules.aspx file anywhere on the net. Have you got any idea how am I suppose to solve this?

Comment: From the first google hit: https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor and binary: http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx